# By executing a simple program of Spring Hibernate integration, I am getting following issue

Tags: java, xml, spring, hibernate, maven

I've got some exceptions in my maven-spring-hibernate project. I think the trouble is in my springg.xml file, but I don't understand where.

Main class

```
package org.db;
import org.hibernate.Query;
import org.model.*;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.List;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

public class App {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException {
                ApplicationContext context =
                new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("springg.xml");
        SessionFactory sessionFactory = (SessionFactory) context.getBean("sessionFactory");
        Session session = sessionFactory.openSession();
        User user = new User("1234","222");
        session.save(user);

        session.flush();


        session.close();
}
```

springg.xml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">
    <bean id="DAO"
          class="org.db.UserDaoImpl">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="sessionFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean id="sessionFactory"
          class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
        <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:hibernate.cfg.xml"/>
    </bean>

    <bean id="dataSource"
          class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
        <property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
        <property name="url"
                  value="jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5433/project_memorina?autoReconnect=true&amp;useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8&amp;characterSetResults=UTF-8"/>
        <property name="username" value="postgres"/>
        <property name="password" value="111"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

hibernate.cfg.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>

        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">org.postgresql.Driver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:postgresql://127.0.0.1:5433/project_memorina</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">postgres</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">111</property>
        <property name="hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>
        <property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
        <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
        <property name="connection.autocommit">true</property>

        <property name="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</property>
        <mapping class="org.model.User" />
        <mapping class="org.model.Settings" />
        <mapping class="org.model.Results"/>
        <mapping class="org.model.LastGame"/>
        <!-- <mapping class="org.model.Cell"/>-->
        <mapping class="org.model.GameCell"/>

    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

my pom.xml of this module

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd"
    xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <artifactId>db</artifactId>
    <version>1.1</version>
    <name>db</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.1</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>model</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp2</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javassist</groupId>
            <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
            <version>3.12.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.15</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-classic</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>ch.qos.logback</groupId>
            <artifactId>logback-core</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.26</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

parent pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Memorina</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.2</version>
            <type>maven-plugin</type>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>4.11</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-util</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.21</version>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
            <version>9.2-1003-jdbc4</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>ejb3-persistence</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.10</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>JBoss repository</id>
            <url>http://repository.jboss.com/maven2/</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <build>
        <finalName>spring-webmvc</finalName>
    </build>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>
    <modules>
        <module>service</module>
        <module>web</module>
        <module>db</module>
        <module>model</module>
    </modules>
</project>
```

error list

```
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'DAO' defined in class path resource [springg.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'sessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [springg.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:359)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1481)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:772)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:834)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:139)
    at org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.<init>(ClassPathXmlApplicationContext.java:83)
    at org.db.App.main(App.java:13)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [springg.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
    ... 20 more
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2693)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2894)
    at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1607)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
    at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:270)
    at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:175)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:212)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:63)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:725)
    at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.isWritableProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:557)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1226)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:543)
    ... 26 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:372)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:360)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 42 more
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are missing `hibernate-core` library.

Add this to yours pom configuration:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: after add dependency have new problem "An AnnotationConfiguration instance is required to use <mapping class="org.model.User"/>"

Comment: Propably it is because you are using `LocalSessionFactoryBean`. You need `AnnotationSessionFactoryBean`. I would suggest to eradicate your `hibernate.cfg` and put all configuration in spring. This is example of `annotatedSessionFactoryBean`: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/hibernate3/annotation/AnnotationSessionFactoryBean.html. This is example of configuration in spring: http://www.byteslounge.com/tutorials/spring-with-hibernate-persistence-and-transactions-example. This is a good start point how to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was caused by different versions of hibernate libraries (copy-paste)

```
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-validator:6.1.6.Final'
implementation 'org.hibernate:hibernate-core:5.4.27.Final'
```

So double check that you use same versions

Answer (score 0):

Remove all the `<version>` tag of your dependencies and let the Spring manage the versions.