# Bean not found error in maven-spring-hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc

I am new to spring-maven-hibernate and i cannot solve this following error
here is my console output. I have tried new dependency in pom.xml such as 5.0.1 hibernate core, but nothing happened.

```
SEVERE: Servlet.service() for servlet [spring] in context with path [/FlightSearchManagement] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'd' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'template' while setting bean property 'template'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'template' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'mysessionFactory' while setting bean property 'sessionFactory'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mysessionFactory' defined in class path resource [applicationContext.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/hibernate/boot/model/naming/ImplicitNamingStrategy] with root cause
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategy
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1363)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1186)
at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2902)
at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1615)
at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.supports(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:54)
at org.springframework.beans.ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.getBeanInfo(ExtendedBeanInfoFactory.java:46)
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.<init>(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:270)
at org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults.forClass(CachedIntrospectionResults.java:189)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getCachedIntrospectionResults(BeanWrapperImpl.java:173)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:226)
at org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl.getLocalPropertyHandler(BeanWrapperImpl.java:63)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.getPropertyHandler(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:739)
at org.springframework.beans.AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.isWritableProperty(AbstractNestablePropertyAccessor.java:571)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1533)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:351)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:108)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1531)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1276)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
```

and this is my class ManageFlightData.java class
    package com.xyz.dao;

```
import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.core.io.ClassPathResource;
import org.springframework.core.io.Resource;

import com.xyz.input.FlightDataInput;
import com.xyz.model.FlightData;

public class ManageFlightData {

    public static void insertFlightData(FlightData flightData) {
        Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);
        FlightDataDAO dao = (FlightDataDAO) factory.getBean("e");
        dao.saveFlightData(flightData);
    }

    public static List<FlightData> searchFlights(FlightDataInput input) {
        Resource r = new ClassPathResource("applicationContext.xml");
        System.out.println("in search");
        BeanFactory factory = new XmlBeanFactory(r);
        FlightDataDAO dao = (FlightDataDAO) factory.getBean("e");
        return dao.searchFlights(input);
    }

}
```

Similarly another DAO class is supposed to get bean "d" with the same logic as above,
my applicationContext.xml is

```
    <bean id="mysessionFactory"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.LocalSessionFactoryBean">
        <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"></property>
        <property name="mappingResources">
            <list>
                <value>UserData.hbm.xml</value>
                <value>FlightData.hbm.xml</value>
            </list>
        </property>
        <property name="hibernateProperties">
            <props>
                <prop 
    key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</prop>
                <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            </props>
        </property>
    </bean>

    <bean id="template"
        class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.HibernateTemplate">
        <property name="sessionFactory" ref="mysessionFactory"></property>
    </bean>
        <bean id="d" class="com.xyz.dao.UserDataDAO">
            <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
        </bean>

        <bean id="e" class="com.xyz.dao.FlightDataDAO">
            <property name="template" ref="template"></property>
        </bean>
    </beans>
```

and finally pom.xml is

```
<packaging>war</packaging>
<name>Spring MVC Example</name>
<description>Spring MVC Hello World Example</description>

<!-- Add Spring Web and MVC dependencies -->
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.9.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <!-- Servlet -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.5.Final</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>8.0.15</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>4.3.2.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <sourceDirectory>src/main/java</sourceDirectory>
    <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.6.1</version>
                <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.0.0</version>
                <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>WebContent</warSourceDirectory>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>

        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName> <!-- added to remove Version from WAR file -->
    </build>
</project>
```

Comment: Try upgrading your Hibernate maven version.

Answer (score 0):

Update your hibernate-core version in pom.xml to 5.x.x .

This should help you solve your problem and subsequent ones:
[By executing a simple program of Spring Hibernate integration, I am getting following issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32519332/by-executing-a-simple-program-of-spring-hibernate-integration-i-am-getting-foll)

Answer (score 0):

You can use annotations `@Component` & `@Autowired`  which is an alternative for initializing the beans.
For example:-

CustomerDAO.java

```
@Component
public class CustomerDAO 
{
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "Hello , This is CustomerDAO";
    }   
}
```

CustomerService.java

```
@Component
public class CustomerService 
{
    @Autowired
    CustomerDAO customerDAO;

    public String test() {
        return customerDAO.toString();
    }
}
```

Comment: So, i read about @Component annotation, it marks a java class as a bean, which means my DAO class will have Component annotation, and Autowired will  inject DAO class beans into UserData and FlightData class( like in UserData class `@Autowired UserDataDAO udao;` )? Am i getting this correctly?